# How to activate idle object evictor for dbcp BasicDataSource 1.4 API

Tags: java, hibernate, apache-commons-dbcp

I want to make sure that **idle object evictor** is enabled for my BasicDataSource connection pool. All the properties related to eviction thread mentioned in [commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html) say that "(If any) idle object evictor is enabled"

Is there property or way by which I can say that **idle object evictor** is enabled for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Got answer for myself after going through documentation for multiple times :)

timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis

> protected long timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis --:
>   The number of
>   milliseconds to sleep between runs of the idle object evictor thread.
>   **When non-positive, no idle object evictor thread will be run.**

It means when value for **timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis** property is positive, **idle object evictor** thread will run.